# MFC header afxwin.h in a dynamic library generating link error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, mfc

I'm trying to use MFC headers, such as `#include <afxwin.h>`, in a dynamic library project.

The structure looks like this:

```
Project Solution
|
|- DynamicLib
     |
     |- main.cc
```

`main.cc` contains the header.

I have the `/MD` compiler flag on, but the solution won't compile.

In the generated `exports.def` file, there's a `__  DATA` field that's causing the issue.

When I remove it manually, the solution compiles.

Here's the (useless) linker error:

```
1>exports.def : warning LNK4022: cannot find unique match for symbol '__'
1>exports.def : warning LNK4002: __@@_PchSym_@00@UwvevolknvmgUlhhprmUxnzpvUlhhprmRyfrowUlhhprmOwriUwvyftUhgwzucOlyq@4B2008FD98C1DD4 defined in MyDir.dir\Debug\stdafx.obj
1>exports.def : warning LNK4002: __@@_PchSym_@00@UzABUPdlipUDUhUrmgvinvwrzgvUexgllohUzgohOmzgrevkilqPBACIAJCBDBUlyqiUznwGEUhgwzucOlyq@4B2008FD98C1DD4 defined in d:\a01\_work\3\s\Intermediate\vctools\atls.nativeproj_1028092131\objr\amd64\stdafx.obj
1>exports.def : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __
```

Is there anything else that should be added to the compiler flags for this to be corrected?

Comment: Having multiple stdafx.obj inputs to a single build seems extremely strange. I would look to why that is happening and likely change so that only one is getting linked in any given configuration.

Comment: The methods mentioned in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2001?view=msvc-170) may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

For someone who might find that question relatable.

I am using CMake as a project file generator and I had `WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS` enabled for my build and that somehow exposed `__` symbol. So you can look if that option was enabled for you.

Hope that will help someone in the future.